# Getting [Object Object] while trying to fetch value

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to fetch the value of my accelerator but it says [object object].

Here is the code which is fetching the value and showing on the html page. I want to get the current value when a button is clicked.

Here is my `home.ts` code:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  private devicemotion0: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject(['-']);
  devicemotion0$: Observable<string[]> = this.devicemotion0.asObservable();

  providers: Provider[] = [
    {
      index: 0,
      subtitle: 'ionic native',
      title: 'device’s accelerometer ',
      availability: Availability.unchecked,
      value: this.devicemotion0$
    },

  constructor(
    private deviceMotion: DeviceMotion,
    private deviceOrientation: DeviceOrientation,
    private platform: Platform,
    private eventManager: EventManager) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkAvailibility();
      this.addEventListener();
    });
  }

  checkAvailibility() {
    let nav: any;
    nav = window.navigator;

    if (nav && nav.accelerometer) { this.providers[1].availability = Availability.available; } else {
      this.providers[1].availability = Availability.notAvailable;
    }

  private addEventListener() {
    let nav: any;
    nav = window.navigator;

    /** LinearAccelerationSensor: Web API */
    if ('LinearAccelerationSensor' in window) {
      const accelerometer = new LinearAccelerationSensor();
      accelerometer.addEventListener('reading', e => { this.accelerationHandler(accelerometer, this.devicemotion0); });
      accelerometer.start();
    }

  private accelerationHandler(acceleration, subject) {
    let info;
    const xyz = '[X, Y, Z]';
    info = xyz.replace('X', acceleration.x && acceleration.x.toFixed(3));
    info = info.replace('Y', acceleration.y && acceleration.y.toFixed(3));
    info = info.replace('Z', acceleration.z && acceleration.z.toFixed(3));
    subject.next(info);
  }

     onClick(){
     alert(this.providers[0].value); // showing [object object]
     alert(this.providers[0].title); // showing device’s accelerometer
}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-button (click)="onClick()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
    Show data
  </ion-button>

  <ion-card *ngFor="let provider of providers">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle> {{ provider.subtitle }} </ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title> {{ provider.title }} </ion-card-title>

...// some code

            <ng-container *ngIf="provider.value | async as value">
              <p>{{ value }}</p>
            </ng-container>
```

Html page screenshot:

[image]

How do I get this **value** inside `onClick()` function?

Comment: Clearly the value in this case is not a string, so you need to use the relevant value of _that_ object.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use an observable for `providers[0].value` ?

Comment: @Emilien  am using premade code, cant change that

Comment: @MikeBrockington , how can i get its value in a string or array inside  `onClick()` function ? even  `alert(this.providers[6].value);` shows `[object object]`

Comment: Try using console.table(this.providers[0].value)  - that should enumerate the entire object for you.

Comment: You _might_ be able to use  this.providers[0].value.toString()

Comment: this.providers[0].value.toString();  didnt worked

Comment: this.providers[0].value also shows [object object]

Comment: Try to console log only the value like `this.providers[0].value.subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: i'll do it and get back in 2 mins

Comment: it  is giving this value in console `ƒ (observerOrNext, error, complete) {
        var operator = this.operator;
        var sink = Object(_util_toSubscriber__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["toSubscriber"])(observerOrNext, error, complete);`

Comment: Hmm .. Don't have any other idea to help you :/ But I would suggest to change the observable into a synchronous value. Otherwise you may have unexpected results

Comment: how do i do  that ? can you guide me from the given code

Answer (score 0):

I will post it as an answer but I don't know if it will solve your issue.

I think you're using an observable but you don't really need it into your array. What if you try this ?

```
private devicemotion0: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject(['-']);

providers: Provider[] = [
{
  index: 0,
  subtitle: 'ionic native',
  title: 'device’s accelerometer ',
  availability: Availability.unchecked,
  value: this.devicemotion0.getValue(),
};
```

Be careful of your `BehaviorSubject`, it's an array of string. So in your .html :

```html
<div>
  <p *ngFor="let item of value">{{ item }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll check this and get back